# Thinkpad t460p external display

Tags: windows, display, thinkpad

I bought a Thinkpad t460p and a 27” 1080p monitor with an ultra dock. All good and fun but the problem is that the screen, specially the desktop it’s fuzzy. The same display on my pc it is very clear, the laptop screeen is 1920x1080 14” and desktop is 1920x1080 75hz, 27” and have only vga and hdmi.

Will I benefit from buying an displayport to hdmi 2.0 adapter?
Windows was fresh install, tried different drivers, also another problem is that on 100% scaling on big monitor icons and menus seems small compared to desktop, I have to apply a 115 scaling to be kind of ok. Tried different drivers,3 displays, hdmi on laptop and on dock, custom resolution from hd 530 control panel.

Comment: What model monitor?

Comment: I have 2 of them, an aoc b27b2da and a xiaomi desktop 27” , all of them was brand new, my issue is with scaling, why I have to use scaling being the same monitor as desktop?